# Why Does Bootstrap Divide The viewport Into 12 Columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frontend

Why does bootstrap divide the viewport into 12 number of columns and not 13 or any other number? I am learning bootstrap for a project and I am curious about this.

Comment: See this: http://www.quora.com/Why-does-Twitter-Bootstrap-3-use-a-12-column-grid-system-by-default/answer/Benjamin-Mailian

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it works for most of the users? If you need more or less columns, you could build your own customized version by adapting the less files.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ > Grid system > @grid-columns

Answer (score 0):

Because 12 can be easily divided equally. 12 is divisible by 12, 6, 4, 3, 2 and 1.

Thus you can have

```
12/12 = 1
12/6 = 2
12/4 = 3
12/3 = 4
12/2 = 6
12/1 = 12 equal columns in a row.
```

> If you think it mathematically, 12 column grid can be divided into any number of odd or even columns since 12 is LCM of 3 and 4.

Source for above: [Yadnesh Patil](http://www.quora.com/Why-does-Twitter-Bootstrap-3-use-a-12-column-grid-system-by-default/answer/Yadnesh-Patil)

This maximum no. of equal columns cannot be achieved with 13, 14, 15 or 16.